# patch file creation var/lib/dpkg/status is failing in chroot environment in ubuntu

Tags: chroot, patch

I am creating customized iso using chroot and fakeroot utility in ubuntu 22.04.

In the end, while creating diff in chroot env using the patch -p1 command (mentioned full command below) getting an error.

Please let us know how to resolve the error.

command and error log :

```
$ diff -u minimal-package-status ubuntu-server-minimal-tree/var/lib/dpkg/status | (cd ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server-tree; patch -p1)

patching file var/lib/dpkg/status

Hunk #1 succeeded at 725 with fuzz 2 (offset 200 lines).

Hunk #2 succeeded at 938 with fuzz 2 (offset 278 lines).

Hunk #3 succeeded at 1629 (offset 448 lines).

Hunk #4 succeeded at 1771 with fuzz 2 (offset 488 lines).

Hunk #5 succeeded at 2071 (offset 670 lines).

Hunk #6 succeeded at 2800 with fuzz 2 (offset 834 lines).

Hunk #7 succeeded at 3818 (offset 1213 lines).

Hunk #8 succeeded at 3940 (offset 1213 lines).

Hunk #9 succeeded at 4201 with fuzz 1 (offset 1254 lines).

Hunk #10 succeeded at 4663 with fuzz 2 (offset 1403 lines).

Hunk #11 succeeded at 4852 (offset 1543 lines).

Hunk #12 succeeded at 5912 with fuzz 2 (offset 1795 lines).

Hunk #13 succeeded at 5995 with fuzz 2 (offset 1587 lines).

Hunk #14 succeeded at 7042 (offset 2258 lines).

Hunk #15 FAILED at 5019.

Hunk #16 succeeded at 7353 (offset 2299 lines).

Hunk #17 succeeded at 7733 with fuzz 2 (offset 2357 lines).

Hunk #18 succeeded at 7938 (offset 2434 lines).

Hunk #19 succeeded at 7953 with fuzz 2 (offset 2434 lines).

Hunk #20 succeeded at 8110 with fuzz 2 (offset 2484 lines).

Hunk #21 succeeded at 8218 (offset 2541 lines).

Hunk #22 succeeded at 8241 with fuzz 2 (offset 2545 lines).

Hunk #23 succeeded at 9430 with fuzz 2 (offset 3073 lines).

Hunk #24 succeeded at 9596 with fuzz 1 (offset 3130 lines).

Hunk #25 succeeded at 10871 (offset 3429 lines).

Hunk #26 succeeded at 10884 (offset 3429 lines).

Hunk #27 succeeded at 11901 (offset 3634 lines).

Hunk #28 succeeded at 12605 (offset 3833 lines).

Hunk #29 succeeded at 12626 (offset 3836 lines).

Hunk #30 succeeded at 14325 (offset 4654 lines).

1 out of 30 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file var/lib/dpkg/status.rej
```

Comment: This is unreadable you may want to format it. From what I can read I do not see a clear question.

Comment: @David I formated please give a solution